# swf not working in Internet explorer

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash, mxml, mxmlc

Why is the below code not working on IE.IS that am i missing anything here.Please let me know

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application
xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
layout="absolute"
width="300"
height="100"
creationComplete="init()">

<mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
     import mx.controls.Alert;
     import flash.net.NetStream;

     private var myMic:Microphone;


     private function init():void {

        Mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
        Mic.setSilenceLevel(0);
        Mic.rate = 44;
        Mic.gain = 100;
        Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.MICROPHONE);
        myMic.setLoopBack(true);

     }

  ]]>
 </mx:Script>

 <mx:ProgressBar x="0" y="36" mode="manual" id="micLevel" label="" labelPlacement="bottom" width="100" fontSize="10" fontWeight="normal"/>


 </mx:Application>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? The SWF can't load?

Comment: No the progress bar does not work.It remains still.Whereas on firefox when spoken on mic the progress bar moves..

Comment: In IE have you provided Flash access to the computer's mic? Usually a dialog pops up to give you access.  If you haven't provided access, then Flash won't be receiving levels from the mic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex actionscript code for activitylevel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585656/flex-actionscript-code-for-activitylevel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, i m a flex developer, and our PHP developers normally look into this matter, but i do have some idea, there are two object tags written in am html file , one for IE browser and other for other browsers like this :

```
 <body>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"    id="index" width="970" height="530"    codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">    <param name="movie" value="http://abc.com/createYourOwnV2.swf" />    <param name="quality" value="high" />    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />    <param name="FlashVars" value="typeId=<?PHP echo $typeId?>&designId=<?PHP echo $designId?>&productId=<?PHP echo $productId?>"/>    <embed src="http://abc.com/createYourOwnV2.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff"
        width="970" height="530" name="index" align="middle"
        play="true"
        loop="false"
        quality="high"
        FlashVars="typeId=<?PHP echo $typeId?>&designId=<?PHP echo $designId?>&productId=<?PHP echo $productId?>"
        allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">    

    </embed>  </object> </body>
```

Hope it helps, ankur

Comment: Sharma:Thanks very much your post helped me a lot